# Is it possible to stub nokogiri xml search methods?

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, nokogiri, stubbing

Let's say that I have a method that looks like this:

```
def raise_if_client_status_error(xml_resp) # xml_resp is Nokogiri::XML object
  unless xml_resp.at('StatusCode').text == 'Success'
    raise ClientError, xml_resp.at('StatusMessage').text
  end
end
```

Is it possible to create an xml_resp_mock and stub the chained call -- `.at('StatusCode').text` -- to return 'Success'?  I'm unsure of the syntax to use, if it's at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to mock Nokogiri in your tests, because it doesn't exhibit any of the [reasons to mock on c2](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MockObject) or [reasons for use on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object#Reasons_for_use). It would be better to pass in a document with  `<StatusCode>Success</StatusCode>` instead. It would be best to mock the methods of the object that would normally read the xml response from the network.